# Can anyone solve phyton list or array problem

Tags: python

My problem is I can't upgrade list index number using for loop and can't add this upgrade number.

Explanation: The length of the string is 5 so there are 5 lines where in each line a substring of the input string, of length equal to the line number is printed i.e. substring with only the letter"D" printed in the first line, substring "DR" of length 2 printed in the 2nd line, "DRE" length of which is 3 being printed in the 3rd line and so on.

Comment: Please show us your code and your output. We can't piece together what the problem is from a vague description. Bear in mind that we can't look over your shoulder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the string with `[:]` operator:

```
s = "abcde"

for i in range(len(s)+1):
    print(s[:i])
```

**Output:**

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
abcde
```